# Google App Engine and OpenID

Tags: python, google-app-engine, openid

I am trying to implement OpenID in a GoogleAppEngine project. In this case, which OpenIDStore I have to use. Thanks

Comment: We need more info in order to help you with this question. For example, are you using Python or Java? Which OpenID library are you using? Do you have example code?

Comment: hey sorry...my mistake...i am using python...i am using the python library given at http://openidenabled.com/
I am open to any other library too.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I try with AEoid which seems alright. Here's [live example](http://www.koolbusiness.com) and [my code](http://montao.googlecode.com)